# Is there a c/c++ lib provide memory pool implementation has stdlib-like interfaces?

Tags: c++, c, memory-pool

I have an idea to create a manually managed continuously block of memory by c/c++ codes, and provides something like:

```
typef struct managedVM
{
  void* pBuffer;
  int length;
}managedVM;

typedef struct managedVMPtr
{
  managedVM* pVM;
  int offset;
}managedVMPtr;

managedVM* mvm_create(int bufferSize);//create a mvm buffer
managedVMPtr mvm_alloc(int size);//like malloc
template<T> managedVMPtr mvm_new(){return mvm_alloc(sizeof(T);}//like new
void mvm_free(managedVMPtr mvmPtr);//like free
```

then I can totally control the memory usage of all data structures allocated in this memory block, and serialize/deserialize the whole memory states at anytime.

I have searched a while for whether some existed open source libs have already achieved these goals and get no result for the lack of my knowledge about c/c++ programing. So I'm looking for some good fortune here, thanks.

Comment: You light want to read up on allocators, a standard c++ feature. See e.g. https://medium.com/@vgasparyan1995/what-is-an-allocator-c8df15a93ed for an introduction.

Comment: what you seem to search for is a (fixed size) memory pool.
You usually keep track of the used memory with a list of blocks that are free and/or used.
I implemented something like this myself recently.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot rely on the virtual memory implementation of the OS?